# Segmentation fault with variadic function

Tags: c

I have been trying to debug this for an hour now, but I am failing. I have a variadic function, set_buffer, that takes in the buffer to set the input strings into

```
void set_buffer(char *buf, int num_str, ...) { // destructively sets buffer with the strings provided, in the order they are provided. Must provide number of arguments so function knows where to stop.
    size_t length = sizeof(buf) / sizeof(*buf); // strlen() fails because it depends on the null terminator...
    printf("length: %d\n", length);
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, num_str); // va_start takes on the NAME of the last known parameter in the function to determine where to start taking in optional arguments
    for (int i = 0, offset = 0; i < num_str && offset < length; ++i) {
        char *str = va_arg(args, char *);
        printf("length of str: %d\n", strlen(str)); // SEG FAULT ERROR
        offset += snprintf(buf+offset, strlen(str)+1, "%s", str); // I must be adding too much of an offset, resulting in a seg fault
        if (i != (num_str - 1)) {
            //offset -= 1;
        }
    }
    va_end(args);
}
```

I suspect it may have something to do with an incorrect fetching of arguments from the va_list args.

Comment: What exactly is your question and why you do not provide a complete minimal working code example that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof(buf) / sizeof(*buf)` only works if `buf` has array type, not a pointer. It will evaluate to a constant 4 or 8 depending whether you're on a 32- or 64-bit target.

You need to pass an argument specifying the available buffer size.

This doesn't exactly point to a crash, since the result is only used for the `offset < length` test. (Which is, by the way, incorrect; you should use `length` to limit the space specified to `snprintf`.) To see what's going wrong, we need a complete, self-contained test case.

Comment: How would I get the size of the buffer outside of the function, since we cant use sizeof()?

Comment: @GeorgeNewton The buffer size is something that needs to be accounted for. Everywhere you pass the buffer, pass its size as well. Use a `struct` if necessary. Or hard-code a conservative size so it is always known beforehand.

Comment: I don't understand. So you're telling me, then when I do char *ptr = malloc(...) - I can't find the length/size unless I hardcode it?

Comment: @GeorgeNewton The argument passed to `malloc` *is* the size. Your responsibility is to save that information. No, the system will not otherwise give it back to you, at least without platform-specific tricks.

Comment: @GeorgeNewton: there is no way to query the allocated memory for its size. You either have to put a terminator inside the memory that you can look for, like the null terminator of a string, or else you have to keep track of the size that you pass to `malloc()`.

Comment: Thank you, potato swatter, you are my hero. Your work has been of tremendous help and I will accept your answer in 2 minutes in accordance with the SO's Fair Social Exchange policy.

Comment: Being a little picky, I'd like to note `sizeof(buf) / sizeof(*buf)` only works if `buf` has array type AND you're in the context in which `buf` was declared.

Comment: @MBlanc Technically, in contexts where it doesn't work, `buf` has type other than array, for example pointer-to-array or plain pointer. A function parameter declared like `foo(int arg[6])` *decays* to `int *`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do `sizeof(buf) / sizeof(*buf)`, since

```
sizeof(buf) == sizeof(char*)
sizeof(*buf) == sizeof(char)
```

So you are effectively doing: `sizeof(char*)/sizeof(char)`